# DatePickerDialog buttons not showing the label

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[image]

The two buttons at the bottom will not show the labels. This is how I am instantiating the date picker `new DatePickerDialog(classname.this, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();`
I am running Android Studio 3.2 Canary and target sdk of 28.

Comment: Please share your styles.xml code

Comment: Changing the colorAccent doesn't seem to change the colour of the text buttons. Is there another value here I can change?`<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorWhite</item></style>`

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to apply material button style :

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button</item>
</style>
```

Result : [materialDatePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puGss.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check for `<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>` in your `styles.xml`, button text color will be same as value of `colorAccent` in `colors.xml`.

Edit:-

Update your style as following, It will work:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyled</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyled</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyled</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogButtonStyled" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Changing the colorAccent doesn't seem to change the colour of the text buttons. Is there another value here I can change?`<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"> <!-- Customize your theme here. --> <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item> <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorWhite</item></style>`

Comment: I have updated my answer please check. I have also tested it. It is working now.